# How to print all values of specific Hashmap key

Tags: java, hashmap

***Current Problem***: I've build a HashMap to save and retrieve some key and values. but i'm not sure how to retrieve all values by a specific name (String). At the moment it's printing all the values from the Hashmap and that's not the thing that i want to achieve.

*In the example below i'm using the following fields*

**Fields**

```
String name
// Object Example
```

**The HashMap**

```
Map<String,Example> mapOfExampleObjects = new HashMap<String,Example>();
```

**The for loop to retrieve the values from the hashmap by a certain key name**

```
for(Map.Entry<String,Example> entry: mapOfExampleObjects.entrySet()){
                    if(mapOfExampleObjects.containsKey(name))
                    {
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
                    }
                }
```

**Current output**

```
John + (Exampleobject)
Ian + (Exampleobject)
Ian + (Exampleobject)
Jalisha + (Exampleobject)
```

**The Output that i want to achieve**

```
Ian + (Exampleobject)
Ian + (Exampleobject)
```

Comment: Why are you looping? A `HashMap` has unique keys. One key, one value.

Comment: There is only 1 value per key.  key = value there is not multiple entries with the same key.

Comment: If you want multiple values for one key, you should use a collection type as the value.

Comment: Right now your looping over the entire set and saying if the key exists then print the current value.  The key exists so you are printing every value.

Comment: You want a `Map<String, List<Example>>`

Comment: key can store one value per entry. If assgien two different value with same key then one value will overlap on another one. Question is not clear.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! My bad, i can solve this problem now.

Comment: I think both the below answer will fit for your issue isn't ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lars, your problem is this line:

```
            if(mapOfExampleObjects.containsKey(name))
```

Your mapOfExampleObjects will always contain the key 'Ian' every time you go through the loop.  What you want is more like:

```
if( name.equals(entry.getKey()) )
```

Comment: Yes, very true as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the `keySet` of the map and manipulate it to select the entries you want:

```
class Example {

    final String name;

    Example(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

public void test() {
    // Sample data.
    Map<String, Example> mapOfExampleObjects = new HashMap<String, Example>();
    mapOfExampleObjects.put("John", new Example("John Smith"));
    mapOfExampleObjects.put("Ian", new Example("Ian Bloggs"));
    mapOfExampleObjects.put("Ian", new Example("Ian Smith"));
    mapOfExampleObjects.put("Jalisha", new Example("Jalisha Q"));
    // Using a Set you can extract many.
    Set<String> want = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("Ian"));
    // Do the extract - Just keep the ones I want.
    Set<String> found = mapOfExampleObjects.keySet();
    found.retainAll(want);
    // Print them.
    for (String s : found) {
        System.out.println(mapOfExampleObjects.get(s));
    }
}
```

Note that this will still only print one `Ian` because a `Map` retains only one value against each key. You will need to use a different structure (perhaps `Map<String,List<Example>>`) to retain multiple values against each key.